# CodeDOM not found assemblies

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, codedom

I just asked a question about compiling with CodeDOM and i got a awesome answer which solved many problems the one problem i have now is how to add the following usings to my compiler

```
System.Diagnostics
&&
Microsoft.Win32
```

when i try with

```
CompilerParameters Params = new CompilerParameters();
Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Diagnostics.dll");
&&
Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.Win32.dll");
```

(Please note that i am adding system.dll and others as forms and drawing, also my code is compiling if it is not using these dlls)

i get the following errors

```
metadata file System.Diagnostics.dll could not be found
```

and the same for Win32

If i get an aswer that will make my day, thanks a lot in advance

Comment: They are namespace names, not assembly names.

Answer (score 1):

As Hans Passant noted, `System.Diagnostics` and `Microsoft.Win32` are *namespaces*, not *assemblies*. What that means is that there is no `System.Diagnostics.dll`, so you can't add it as a reference.

In .Net, one assembly can contain multiple namespaces and a single namespace can be contained in multiple assemblies. If you look at the documentation for a class, it always lists its namespace *and* its assembly. For example, for [the `Process` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx), it's:

> **Namespace:**  System.Diagnostics
>   **Assembly:**  System (in System.dll)

Answer (score 1):

I have had success with the following:

```
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof(TTarget).Assembly.ManifestModule.FullyQualifiedName);
```